# Wall of flesh not spawning

Tags: terraria

I've had a lot of difficulty summoning the wall of flesh. The first time I summoned it when I was new to the game I died. I waited for my guide to respawn so I could try again but he never spawned. I made a house for him to stay in but he still has not come. It's been 4 weeks and he has not come. Is there any way to make him come back that I don't know of, or is this some glitch

Comment: The NPCs kind of queue up  in the order they will appear, all the other pending ones have to show up before the Guide will... Just something else that might be going on.

Comment: @james 4 weeks is more than enough time for all NPCs to spawn, and I'm pretty sure the Guide is first

Comment: In my game it says stuff like 'Logan (my guide) would like to settle down' but I searched my world and can't find him in the world or on the map. The only other Npc I have is the goblin tinkerer and he is on the map. How long should it take for the guide to red pawn?

Comment: If it says he would like to settle down then it means he can't find a house to do it in. You might want to check the house you built for him to see if it's valid. One of the first things I do most worlds is build about twenty houses.

Comment: @Aequitas If you do not make room for them to all show up then the time does not matter. You have to be able to accommodate all the pending in order to get the killed ones to show up again.. that is all I was getting at.

Comment: @James really!? Are you sure about that? Surely the ones that do have available housing would spawn and the rest wouldnt? If you're 100% sure about that can you add it to the answer in the linked question please.